# d3.js: map with ortographic projection - how to choose proper clipAngle()

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, map-projections

I'm creating a visualization containing three maps, and are struggeling with finding the right value to put in clipAngle(). From what I've read, 90 should be good, it works with map 0 and 1, but not with map 2 (then it returns a filled circle - this also happens sometimes when I try to rotate the map).

Here is the working code (this is very much work in progress): http://vibekehauge.com/jordoverflatenspuslespill.html

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (i.e. why do you set `clipAngle()` at all)?

Comment: I am trying to display the maps properly. If I remove `clipAngle()` I get a negative shape where the land overlaps (like Australia and South America).

Comment: You might have to choose different angles for different maps.

Comment: Hm, ok. Even though they show the same thing (all of them are world maps, same size, and with the same settings when exported to shapefiles and then from shapefiles to topojson)?
Could the `scale` values in my topojson have something to say? All of my maps are in the same topojson and therefore have the same `scale` values.